# ObjC structs of floats in arrays: Compact way to avoid NSValue?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, struct

I'm to port some JS to native ObjC code. Since a struct won't fit inside arrays, it needs to be wrapped.

The JS code goes as follows:

```
var bezierVertices = [{0: 14},{10: 32},{24: 16}];
```

Plain and easy JS: Array of anonymous objects.

I'm bound to the following requirement: Have the code as compact as possible, meaning I've been refused when proposing an NSArray of NSValue using [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:ccp(x,y)]

Going down the malloc way doesn't fit this criterion either. They want something as compact as the JS stated above.

Before writing something as ugly as an NSString like @"0:14;10:32;24:16"; that's split and parsed in a loop, I thought SO could help bring something clean :)
I'm allowed to use .mm so ObjC++ solutions could fit as well, but I'm not knowledgeable about C++ at all...

Thanks!
J.

Comment: Maybe you should do your homework yourself...

Comment: @dasdom: One can never say for sure, but that doesn't look much like homework.

Comment: Objective-C is a verbose language that avoids formal grammar for most things; whoever is getting you to port is acting incredibly unreasonably.

Comment: @dasdom And the added value of your input? If you read til the end, you'll see I'm questioning my own solution. Without external advice, I can't tell how wrong/accurate my workaround is. One should stay humble and enjoy pair programming sometimes...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> They want something as compact as the JS stated above

Who's "they"?  Do "they" have any understanding that Objective-C is a compiled language and the "compactness" of the source code is largely irrelevant?

Anyway, rant over.  You can make a C array of CGPoints like this:

```
CGPoint myArray[] = {{0.0, 14.0}, {10.0, 32.0}, {24.0, 16.0}};
```

This is a standard C array initialiser.  You get the number of elements like this:

```
int nElements = sizeof myArray / sizeof(CGPoint);
```

Comment: You mean: `int nElements = sizeof myArray / sizeof(CGPoint);` ← CGPoint not CGFloat.

Comment: @JeremyP Hey thanks, that looks like it's gonna solve this efficiently! Ranting, "they" is the client I'm working for, more specifically the "senior architect" staff bloke who's done only bits of VB6 :)

Comment: @JeremyP oh yeah, the why, it's to allow graphics designers to input coordinates of polygonish shapes around images they designed. Another great quote: "It needs to look like json, otherwise they're lost" :-)

Comment: @Jem: Ah, in that case, you'd do better to have a separate text file containing the coordinates actually in JSON and your Objective-C program would then read it and parse the JSON itself.  I wouldn't like to let graphical designers amend source code.

Comment: @JeremyP indeed, I hadn't thought about this. Great idea!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to manage variable-length arrays of vertices, C++ provides `std::vector<CGPoint>`.